# C# File Upload: calling a function right after selecting the file

Tags: c#, file-upload

I am trying to call a function immediately after I choose a file.

I want the function to be something like this:

```
private void FileSelected()
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        if (CheckFileType(FileUpload1.FileName))
        {
            String filePath = "Cert/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            txtpath1.Text = filePath;
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "You can upload ony images or PDF files.";
        }
    }
}
```

So when a file is selected, the function `FileSelected()` must be called immediately. And then as you can see above, the `FileSelected()` will then be calling another function `CheckFileType()`.

```
private bool CheckFileType(string fileName)
{
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    switch (ext.ToLower())
    {
        case ".gif":
        case ".png":
        case ".jpg":
        case ".jpeg":
        case ".pdf":
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }

}
```

So how to call a function directly after selecting a file without having to click on any button?

Comment: Can you also share file selection code?

Comment: Since the file is selected within the web browser, and your C# code does not run until the whole form is submitted to the server, you can't do this. You _could_ re-write the same CheckFileType function in JavaScript to run when the file input's value changes, or you could even make an ajax call to the server separately to call a C# method (after the same "change" event in JS), although that seems a little bit pointless when you could just do the check in JS (and of course double-check it on the server-side when the form is submitted, because client-side validation can be bypassed :-) ).